# Notepad++ issue VBScript code appearing on .html files

Tags: notepad++, html, vbscript

Hi guys I am having problems with notepad++. Everytime I close an HTML file there is always a vbscript code that appears below the HTML file. Is this a virus with notepad++? The VB script code does not appear on other file formats only on HTML files. any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would be helpfull if you posted the VBScript that gets attached.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos here is the code. I have to remove the numbers on the Writedata because it was too long http://pastebin.com/CCMuEvES

Comment: I think that's virus. There must be some sort of plugin or executable attached to Notepad++!

Comment: @undone Any idea how I can remove any of those? I have already Uninstalled and Reinstalled Notepad++ but it still appears on my HTML files..

Comment: No, I had something similar, even my anti-virus couldn't find the source. I had to reinstall my windows.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you open the file in Notepad?

Comment: @snowdude Yup the VBScript also appears when I open the HTML file on notepad

Comment: Well at least you can confirm it's not a Notepad++ plug-in issue. It looks like something much nastier.

Comment: It turns out that this is a virus called vbs heur.. all I need to do now is find a way to remove this without losing all the HTML files i made in the past 3 months :(

Answer (score 0):

Open N++ plugins manager dialog, and see, if some DLL present there that may do this.
If not, then try

- remove your N++ folder,
- reinstall N++, and make it portable (option in installer).